# KS-Score Methods

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, data-science-model

I came across 2 methods to calculate KS-Score and select best probability threshold.

1. Decible Method
2. TPR - FPR

Is there any specific scenario on which it depends which method to select.
or we cna choos e any method any time.

Also I get a different best cut-off through both the methods. So in such case, which one to select.